# jquery selected value of select box doesn't change result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the price result using `.change` on the storage select box by using the chrome console but what happens is that the price doesn't update.

I tried different other ways such as `.click` `.trigger` , still the select box switches between 16gb to 64gb back and forth but the price doesn't update. The price only updates when I manually change the select box value with the mouse.

What might be causing it not to switch? Are there any alternative way to trigger the event by code?

*** edit: this is not my code, I am just trying to understand how to get the data if the `.click` doesn't work through the console

[image]

Comment: And where is your code?

Comment: sorry i should of precised it is not my code but im looking how to mimic a click on this code

Answer (score 0):

The `click()` method is not necessary unless you explicitly want to trigger that event.

I've added a `click()` event listener and call on the last change here.

```js
var select = $("#test_select");

select.on('click', function() {
  alert('click event');
});

setTimeout(function() {
  select.val("2");
}, 1000);
setTimeout(function() {
  select.val("3");
}, 2000);
setTimeout(function() {
  select.val("4");
}, 3000);
setTimeout(function() {
  select.val("5").click();
}, 4000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="test" id="test_select">
  <option value="1" selected>1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: yeah that's the thing, i want the event to happen but it only changes when i manually click on it

Comment: hmm... it works in this updated example as expected. how are you building your select options? e.g. is it this? `<option value="16gb">16gb</option>` because the `val()` method is searching on the value part, not the text part: `<option value="value_part">text_part</option>`